# How to define a random variable

Tags: probability-theory

I'm writing a paper and have to define a random variable on an infinite sample space $S'$. The sample space consists of sequences of elements from a set $S$.

A random variable is a function which maps a sample space to a measurable space. A measurable space consists of a set and a sigma-algebra. So when we have to formally define a random variable, do we have to mention the particular sigma-algebra as well? What notation/convention is generally used for this? (The set in my case is the extended real numbers).

This is what I'm currently doing. I'm currently using $\rho \in S'$ as an element of the sample space. We define the random variable $T$ on $S'$ as follows
$$
 T(\rho) = \begin{cases}
  t_{\rho} \quad \text{if converged},  \\
  \infty \quad \text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}
$$
where $t_\rho$ is some constant dependent on the sequence $\rho$. I discuss the probability distribution just after this. Is this correct? Do I have to talk about the measurable space? Is saying $T(\rho) = \infty$ correct? or should it be $T(\rho) = (\infty, X)$ where $X$ is some set from the measurable space? I'm a bit confused from the definition of the measurable space. Thanks!